# type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast Getting this error again and again

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, casting

```
Expanded(
              child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: _databaseRef,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                    Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                  final data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                  final influencer =
                      Influencer.fromMap(data as Map<String, dynamic>);
                  return buildInfluencerCard(influencer as DataSnapshot);
                },
              ),
            ),

Widget buildInfluencerCard(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    final influencer =
        Influencer.fromMap(snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);

    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(influencer.profilePicture),
        ),
        title: AppText(text: influencer.username),
        subtitle: AppText(text: 'Followers: ${influencer.followerCount}'),
        trailing:
            AppText(text: 'Engagement Rate: ${influencer.engagementRate}%'),
      ),
    );
  }

factory Influencer.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Influencer(
      name: map['name'] as String? ?? '',
      profilePicture: 'assets/images/dummy_profile_pic.png',
      username: map['username'] as String? ?? '',
      followerCount: map['followerCount'] as int? ?? 0,
      engagementRate: (map['engagementRate'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0.0,
      creditPoints: (map['creditPoints'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0.0,
    );
```

Getting the list from firebase database and displaying them

Answer (score 0):

please make sure the response of your future builder on on snapshot.
i think the result is not meet data type.
since you cast the response with :
`final data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

i think you should debug it first